# Connect MySQL with C++ on MacOS using VSCode

Tags: c++, mysql, macos, visual-studio-code, mysql-connector

I'm trying to build a crud app with C++ but i'm stuck on the installation and configuration of mysql on c++ on my mac. I've already installed `mysql-connector-c++` using brew install. Now, I'm managing to connect mysql on my c++ app. If anyone can help me or can provide a documentation for this case, It would be very helpful. Thank you.
MySQL - C++ - MacOS - VSCode